# Open Google Drive PDF viewer on Android error cannot open file when the first attempt get cancel by user

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I've recently developed android app to use Chrome custom tab, when user click link which will open pdf file, Chrome tab automatically open default pdf viewer which basically for most of android device - Google Drive pdf viewer will be a default app.

In normal situation everything work well when user waiting a download to finish and open PDF but when user change their mind and click back to cancel downloading the file in the middle it will kill application and go back to the main app where user was click link to. Now when user click that link (The same link) again and wait for the download to finish, this time when download finish pdf viewer will get error saying 'Cannot display pdf, pdf file cannot be opened'

Now when user click the same link (from error) for the third time, pdf viewer can open file normally. you can reproduce your problem as well in any app like facebook to open chrome custom tab, share this link in facebook

http://www.hk-lawyer.org/sites/default/files/field/journal/201509_HK_Lawyer.pdf

first time click open, no wait download to finish then cancel, second time click open wait download to finish now you will get error, third time click open wait download to finish now you can open, after that it get from cache no problem.

This really make user experience feel so bad when the file is very big (mobile data usage get used). anyone facing the same problem, is this Drive pdf viewer problem?

Comment: Have you tried other files and reproduce the same error result? You may want to check how your code handle canceled request. Given the scenario, downloading the file(2nd time) may have used the cancelled download request, making an invalid pdf content file.

Comment: It is just a http url link to open via chrome custom tab, there is no problem with normal link,  In the code to call chrome custom tab - `customTabsIntent.launchUrl(activity, Uri.parse(url));`, do you know how to handle cancelled download request which basically chrome will open Drive pdf viewer as a default app? if the android user choose different pdf viewer this problem might not occurs, is this a bug in Google Drive pdf viewer? @Mr.Rebot